# include a line break in a value

Tags: php, phpword

I have a word template where there are values defined in the php code:
In php code:

```
$document->setValue('Value1', $value1);
```

In word template:

```
${Value1}
```

How can I include a value including a break line between two values to include in the value of the word?

Answer (score 5):

Replace `\n` with `</w:t><w:br/><w:t>`

```php
$value1 = str_replace("\n", '</w:t><w:br/><w:t>', $value1);
$document->setValue('Value1', $value1);
```

Taken from [https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/issues/838](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/issues/838#issuecomment-334104306)

Comment: Works for me in PHPWord 0.18.2.

Answer (score 0):

## You cannot.

This is because you're neither producing HTML, as the people suggesting `nl2br()` and such seem to be thinking, nor producing ASCII text, which is where `\n` might help you.

You are writing a **PHPWord template**.

So your "newline" is actually **adding a paragraph**, which is way more complex than simply inserting a `<br>` tag.

The documentation [states clearly](https://phpword.readthedocs.io/en/latest/templates-processing.html) that what you want is not possible:

> You can create an OOXML document template with included search-patterns (macros) which can be replaced by any value you wish. **Only single-line values can be replaced**.

## So what do you do?

You can perhaps change the template so that it has two values separated by a line break (so actually you have one value in one paragraph and one value in another). Then, set the two values independently. Keep one empty if you don't want it to show (it will still be an empty paragraph).

Or you can use a repeatable block and again add the two values in both subblocks. Or prepare two subblocks and then delete one if it is not needed. See to this effect [sample 23](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/develop/samples/Sample_23_TemplateBlock.php).

In general, PHPWord templating is only for *very simple documents* (i.e., groups of documents which differ only slightly one from another: for example a mass mailing, where only the name and address changes). For more complex operations you need to use the full PHPWord APIs, and in this case, issue two `addText()` calls, or only one, depending on whether the newline is there or not.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to @david's answer

```
$value1 = 'Hello \nWorld';
$value1 = str_replace('\n', '</w:t><w:br/><w:t>', $value1);  // use single quotes for \n if your string is wrapped in single quotes
$document->setValue('Value1', $value1);
```

Answer (score -1):

In a string, a line break is represented by an "/n" but I am not sure if thats what youre searching for.

```
blabla = "hello /n whats up"
print(blabla)
//output : hello
//whats up
```

Comment: You mean `\n`, not `/n`.

Answer (score -1):

The answer above me is incorrect

You can use HTML tags in php value so you can put `<br>` for the line break

```
<?php

$comment = "hello <br> whats up";
echo $comment;

?>
```

that will output:

```
hello
whats up
```

Comment: Answers change order here. Please edit and specify *exactly which* answer in incorrect and why. Thanks