# phpword template dynamic block

Tags: php, docx, phpword, word-template

I have a word template with this content

```
${line1}
```

${line1} template content value from sql is

```
${block_name} 
${var1}  
${block_name}
```

Using PhpWord TemplateProcessor, I am able to replace this. In TemplateProcessor.php, I have add

```
$replace = preg_replace('~\R~u', '</w:t><w:br/><w:t>', $replace);
```

in function setValue. This is because, the block should be multiline and have no space in order cloneblock to happen.

Then, I save as template2.docx and load again in new TemplateProcessor(). When I open the word file, it already display multiline. But, still cloneblock could not be achieved.

```
include "db.php";

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor;
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory;
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord;

//1
$templateProcessor = new TemplateProcessor('template.docx');    
//template content value
$templateContentValue=$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$content        =$templateContentValue[0]['contentVal'];
$templateProcessor->setValue('line', $content);
//save as template2.docx
$pathToSave     ='template2.docx';
$templateProcessor->saveAs($pathToSave);

//2
$templateProcessor2 = new TemplateProcessor($pathToSave);
$replacements = array(
                            array('var1' => 'value1'),
                            array('var1' => 'value2'),
                        );
$templateProcessor2->cloneBlock('block_name', 0, true, false, $replacements);
$templateProcessor2->saveAs('output.docx');
```

Expected Output:

```
value1
value2
```

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you got a typo in the block syntax on last line

By referring to [cloneBlock](https://phpword.readthedocs.io/en/latest/templates-processing.html#cloneblock) documentation, you are missing a slash(/) in you template content of **${line1}**, the content value should be

```
${block_name} 
${var1}  
${/block_name} // last line of block syntax
```

In your first word template with content

```
${line1}
```

I see your code with

```
$templateProcessor->setValue('line', $content);
```

shouldn't it be ?

```
$templateProcessor->setValue('line1', $content);
```

So I assume it might just a typo when you're writing the post, which it is not the main issue here.

Another possibility that I can think of after testing using the suggestion from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56620136/include-a-line-break-in-a-value/56622080#56622080) with multiline value is, it might due to the unrecognized syntax of ***newline*** by PHPWord in your replacement content of **${line1}**.

I try with following for frist word template :

```
${line1}
${line2}
${line3}
```

Then replace multi values at once

```
$templateProcessor->setValues([
  'line1' => '${block_name}',
  'line2' => '${var1}',
  'line3' => '${/block_name}'
]);

// same goes to your code starting at line ==> //save as template2.docx
```

The output is as expected, but I don't think this is what you preferred.

Hope it helps!